# Modeling a Go/Reversi Board in iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, grid

I'm trying to create a Go/Reversi board.

[image: go board]
<sub>(source: [xmp.net](http://senseis.xmp.net/diagrams/29/ad217a381dbb8bc75d8420f6aec40af5.png))</sub>

I'm not sure how I would go about doing this.
I tried looking up how to use UICollectionView but it's really confusing.  And the examples I've seen online seem outdated or they don't really have a MxN grid structure

The goal is to be able to touch a spot on the board and create a Go piece at that location.
I also need to be able to look at the positions of neighboring pieces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to draw the grid manually. [iOS drawing guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)  will help.
Also here is fine [RayWenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/29228/how-to-develop-an-ipad-board-game-app-part-12)

Comment: Learning of custom drawing and CoreAnimation framework is a great way to understand how standard views works. If you want to learn iOS - implement whole game, if not - just find some source and change titles.